# Is there a way to display html 5 web pages into android/ios app?

Tags: android, ios

I have a website which needs authentication. Each user can have some personalized graphics. I am looking for a way to create an app which displays the graphics for a particular user when he logs in using the app. Is there an existing solution for this which I can OEM to create my app.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is not very clear, please consider editing it to include a specific problem (This line of code should do that but instead, I get that, why?). [This help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, your question is very broad. Generally speaking, an app can display any web page using a WebView.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I am looking more into an existing solution, like an app which can be customized. Or any other easy way rather than creating a new app.

Comment: It strongly depends on your needs. As I said, displaying a web page itself is a very simple task but I guess that this won't be the only thing that you need, right? If the webpage is the only thing, then why not leave it a webpage and just have the users open Chrome/Safari and use the web page?

Comment: However, I strongly encourage you to ask this question in the [java chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java) once you have enough reputation as such broad questions are likely to be closed.

Comment: The web pages have some graphic data which is useful for our customers. It's just the ease of opening an app over a web page. Thanks for your reply!